# .htaccess RewriteRule not working

Tags: apache-2.4, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a windows environment using WAMP where this works fine.  I am just setting up my Ubuntu desktop development environment, and this particular mod_rewrite is not working.

It's pretty basic, but if I go to
`example.local/files/a-real-file.pdf` I get a `404 not found` from apache.  If I go to
`example.local/files.php/a-real-file.pdf` the file will display, as expected.  If I go to
`example.local/files.php/non-existing-file.who.cares` I get a `var_dump($thelink)` as expected from my `files.php` logic.

the `.htaccess` in my web root

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^files/(.*)$ files.php/$1
```

my apache vhost config

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName reqapp.localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/aaApp/public_html
    <Directory /var/www/html/aaApp/public_html/>
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

and for good measure, the "localhost" conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName localhost
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

as well as the "applicable" part of `apache2.conf`

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

according to `phpinfo()` `mod_rewrite` is loaded.  If a create a syntax error in the `.htaccess` file, the site does crash.

I don't know where else to look.  I can't fine any other `.conf` files in and of the "{mods|conf|sites}-enabled" files that should be effecting this directory.

It might be worth mentioning that I also have a Joomla instance running, and the SEF is working fine with it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ```
> Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
> ```

You need to disable `MultiViews` (or simply *not enable it*). For example:

```
Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
```

Or remove it altogether from the `Options` directive if it is has not already been enabled on the server.

With `MultiViews` enabled, mod_negotiation will trigger an internal subrequest for `files.php` (without the additional *pathname information* that is required for your request to be successful) *before* mod_rewrite gets to test the request. So the `RewriteRule` *pattern* never matches and the rewrite does not occur.

#### In detail...

MultiViews is part of mod_negotiation (content-negotiation). The issue in your case is that you are requesting `/files/...` (in a valid directory - the document root) and a file with that basename (ie. `files`) exists in that directory. If you were to request `/bar/...` (which presumably does not exist)  then you would not have experienced this problem.

When you requested `/files/...`, MultiViews results in Apache *searching* for an appropriate resource (`files.*` - essentially trying various file extensions) until a response with the expected mime-type is found. The "problem" is that this happens very early in the request, so will often conflict with mod_rewrite.

MultiViews is a simple way of enabling extensionless URLs (no URL rewriting is required). However, as soon as you need to do something a little more complex then it will likely conflict with mod_rewrite - a common problem. MultiViews is not enabled on Apache by default (however, some *shared* hosts do enable it).

Comment: Awesome! that was it.  I don't even know what MultiViews is.  I just copied the section from what WAMP did.  To be honest, I think I only need FollowSymLinks

Comment: Yes, you probably only need `FollowSymLinks` (but you should explicitly disable `Indexes` with `-Indexes` since it is enabled for `/var/www/`) . `Indexes` allows Apache to generate directory listings (which is generally not desirable) and `Includes` enables SSI. I've updated my answer with more info about MultiViews.

Comment: Thanks for the update! Always good to know the why!